# how can I Create custom App drawer flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-painting, flutter-custompainter

How can I create custom app drawer like this one

[image]

I tried to use custom shape border with container but I cannot get the same shape

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it using this,

```
 class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback drawerClose;
  final Size size;
  const CustomDrawer({
    super.key,
    required this.size,
    required this.drawerClose,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,//where your Drawer needs to be
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius:
            const BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(100)),
        child: Container( //add your designs here
          height: size.height,
          child: Drawer(
            // add drawer items
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```